# News Solution with SharePoint 2013 on-prem

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, search

I am struggeling with something:

Requirement:

1. Each team / teamsite (`http://sp13/teams/it`) should have the option to create a news element.
2. The news element has the option where it should be shown as a dropdown with the values:

   - Internal -> `sp13/teams/it`
   - External -> `sp13/teams/it` + `sp13/teams`
   - Important -> `sp13/teams/it` + `sp13/teams` + `sp13/`

Also each news element has to have it's own `pictureURL` field value depending on the department.

If I want to work with SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflows it is quite hard to do all those workflows for all teamsites and it is difficult to get the element updated if I copy the element in all there lists.

But I need the elements which are `Important` in one list because I want to display them different and the code is not ready to use it as a display template. Otherwise search (search results) would be the best here, I think.

Any recommendations?

Comment: What does *not ready to use it as a display template*  mean ? This usecase is a prime example where Search and Display Templates shine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked a lot the last two days, but now I have a solution which is perfect for my requirement.

News solution over multiple sites (en) in SharePoint 2013 with one list, a lot of comfort and style!

https://afrait.com/blog/news-solution-over-multiple-sites-en

*Here a short abstract:*

I have just ONE list which is called news and created at sp13/ with all the columns I need....

[image]

...If we check now the news list we see, that there is the element and also the workflow fired....

Hope this will also help some of you guys!

Answer (score 2):

Could you not create yourself a custom content type that inherits from the base and then apply to the sites (this could be done with PowerShell).  From there you create a Workflow against that Content Type and deploy to all the team sites.  This way you are only creating the WF once, but it is reusable by all the other sites because they all share the same content type.